# How to link css to html on TextEdit

Tags: html, css

Take a look at my code. Tell me what I am doing wrong.

CSS File - Name style.css

```css
#color{
background-color: #yellow;
}
```

HTML File

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”css/style.css” type=”text/css”>



<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id=“color”> color </div>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Is my HTML link wrong?

This is the updated HTML File

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 



<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="color"> color </div>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the # symbol: `background-color: #yellow;`.

Comment: the below answers should be working already. If it still doesn't I think the problem is in your path of css. Verify that this href="css/style.css" is a correct  path

Answer (score 3):

It's either : `background-color:yellow;` or `background-color:#FFE51E;` but not `background-color:#yellow;`

Plus you are using the wrong quotation marks : ”  instead of " and you have to put `link` tags in `head` tags.

Which gives us this :
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxssd7L6/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="color"> color </div>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed it but it still doesn't turn it yellow.

Comment: You are using the wrong quotation marks use " not ”. Consider using a better text editor than TextEdit if don't let you use the correct one.

Comment: I changed it but it still didn't work.

Comment: You need to put `link` tags in `head` tags too...

Comment: so do I need to put it in `HTML` tag and `head` tag or just the the `head` tag.

Comment: Just in `head` tags.

Comment: I also tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: The code is correct (working for me) where did you put your CSS stylesheet ? By looking at the path it should be in a folder named "css" in your project/site root.

Answer (score 0):

the # symbol us used for the hexadecimal color like #fff if you wanna one of the colors by name you just use the name without any symbol:

```
background-color: yellow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/443x398u/1/)

**CSS:**

```
#color{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html> 
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="color"> color </div>
      <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

- your doing wrong in your css ***background-color: #yellow;*** is wrong. It should be ***background-color: yellow;*** or ***background-color: #FFFF00;***.
- you are using *External Styling* of CSS so add a link to it in the `<head>` section of the HTML page
- If this still doesn't work check the path of your css. Are you sure this is a correct path? 
  `href="css/style.css"`
- Here's a tutorial how to use background-color http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp and here's the list of colors in css http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it by taking out the path for the link. I had copied it on by accident and that was why it wasn't working. Here is the working code.

```css
#color{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 



<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="color"> color </div>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is how to link style sheet in text editor. If you use text editor , first thing you should do is to put all the  (.css, .js, .html) into one folder. Then you can use only your file name with the extension to link. This is the easiest way if you use text editor. In this case I think you have linked external stylesheet properly. I guess thr problrm is with 'background-color:yellow;' don't use # with color name.